# Forming a first degree function from a collection of equations and constants

Tags: matlab

So I have a container with $V=Ah$ of liquid. $h_0$ is the starting height of the liquid and the amount of liquid the containers changes at $q=kh$, where $q$ is the rate of liquid draining per time unit, $k$ is a constant and $h$ is the height of the water at $t$. The amount of liquid going out of V is directly proportionate to the amount going out based on q.

Now I'm to write up a first degree function h(t), that will determine the height of the liquid at time $t$. What I came up with was $h(t)=h_0-khA^{-1}$.

$A$, $h_0$, $k$, $q_0$ and $h_0$ are known, so if the function is ok in and of itself, then the only problem I have is that I need to find a way to get the last remaining $h$ out from the function, or else I'd have to use equation solver for the function which is not a suitable solution.

How would I be able to modify the function so that matlab could handle solving $h$ at $t$ and so that I can make a graph out of it?